# Variation of a signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

This is Exercise 3.P in Bartle's *The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure*. I think I have a proof but would appreciate it if anyone can spot any mistakes or suggest any improvements.

---

If $\mu$ is a charge [Bartle's term for a finite signed measure] on a sigma-algebra $\Sigma$, let $\nu$ be defined for $E \in \Sigma$ by
$$\nu(E) = \sup \sum_{j=1}^{n}|\mu(A_j)|$$
where the supremum is taken over all finite disjoint collections $\{A_j\}$ in $\Sigma$ with $E = \cup_{j=1}^{n} A_j$. Show that $\nu$ is a measure on $\Sigma$. (It is called the **variation** of $\mu$.)

---

It is clear that $\nu(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\nu(E) \geq 0$ for all $E \in \Sigma$, so we need to show that $\nu$ is countably additive. Suppose that $(E_k)$ is a disjoint sequence of sets in $\Sigma$ whose union is $E$. For each $k$, let $\{A_{jk}\}_{j=1}^{n_k}$ be a finite disjoint collection of sets in $\Sigma$ such that $E_k = \cup_{j=1}^{n_k}A_{jk}$. Then
$$\{A_{jk} : k=1,\ldots,N\ \text{and}\ j=1,\ldots,n_k\}\ \text{and}\ E\setminus(\cup_{k=1}^{N}E_k)$$
is a finite disjoint collection of sets in $\Sigma$ whose union is $E$. Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{n_k}|\mu(A_{jk})| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{n_k}|\mu(A_{jk})| + |\mu(E\setminus(\cup_{k=1}^{N}E_k))| \leq \nu(E)$$
Taking the supremum for each fixed $k$, we obtain
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\nu(E_k) \leq \nu(E)$$
Taking the limit as $N \to \infty$, it follows that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\nu(E_k) \leq \nu(E)$$
For the reverse inequality, fix $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\{B_m\}_{m=1}^{M}$ be a finite disjoint collection of sets in $\Sigma$ whose union is $E$, such that
$$\nu(E) \leq \sum_{m=1}^{M}|\mu(B_m)| + \epsilon$$
Note that $\{B_m \cap E_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable disjoint collection of sets in $\Sigma$ whose union is $B_m$. Since $\mu$ is a charge, it is countably additive, so
$$\mu(B_m) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_m \cap E_k)$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{aligned}
\nu(E) &\leq \sum_{m=1}^{M}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_m \cap E_k)\right| + \epsilon \\
&\leq \sum_{m=1}^{M}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\mu(B_m \cap E_k)| + \epsilon \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{M}|\mu(B_m \cap E_k)| + \epsilon \\
\end{aligned}$$
Changing the order of the summation is valid because of Tonneli’s Theorem, that is, the summands are nonnegative, so the double sum can be performed in any order without changing the result, even if it is infinite. Now $E_k$ is the disjoint union of $\{B_m \cap E_k : m = 1,\ldots,M\}$, so
$$\sum_{m=1}^{M}|\mu(B_m \cap E_k)| \leq \nu(E_k)$$
Therefore,
$$\nu(E) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\nu(E_k) + \epsilon$$
Since this inequality holds for any $\epsilon > 0$, we conclude that
$$\nu(E) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\nu(E_k)$$

Comment: By the way, I *think* it's true that the double sum $\sum_{m=1}^{M}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\mu(B_m\cap E_k)|$ is in fact finite, although my proof doesn't require this. My reasoning: by countable additivity, $$\mu(E) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{m=1}^{M}\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(B_m \cap E_k)\right) = \sum_{m=1}^{M}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(B_m \cap E_k)$$ Since the union can be taken in any order, the sum must also have this property. Therefore the sum cannot be conditionally convergent, so it must be absolutely convergent. Is there a flaw in this reasoning?

Comment: One more thing, I just noticed a glitch in the proof of the reverse inequality: if $\nu(E)$ is infinite, then it's not possible to choose a disjoint finite set $\{B_m\}$ such that $\nu(E) \leq \sum_{m=1}^{M}|\mu(B_m)| + \epsilon$. However, fixing $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we can instead satisfy the inequality $\min(\nu(E), N) \leq \sum_{m=1}^{M}|\mu(B_m)| + \epsilon$ and proceed as in the proof. Then at the end, we can let $N \to \infty$, so that $\min(\nu(E), N) \to \nu(E)$ (whether finite or not). I'll edit the proof with this workaround when I get the chance.

Comment: With your observation of taking $N$ when $\nu(E)=\infty$, this proof is spotless. Thank you for sharing.